# PHP - Rename all files in folder to 1.ext, 2.ext, 3.ext

Tags: php, file, rename

... and of course, with .ext, I mean, preserve the original extension!

Now this question has been asked before, but weirdly, the answer doesn't even remotely work. For me, that is.

Now, I started with this:

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$fileFolder.'/';
$i = 1; 
$handler = opendir($directory);
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $newName = $i . '.jpg';
        rename($file, $newName);
        $i++;
    }
}
closedir($handler);
```

Seems pretty straightforward to me, yet it doesn't rename any files...
Does anyone have a clue what is going wrong?
Or just a working snippet... :D

Comment: I'm going to guess permission errors.

Comment: does $fileFolder start with a '/', if not: it should.

Comment: @luk2302: It does! The whole script, except for the rename bit, already works for simply reading a folder's content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the full relative/absolute name when you are renaming, not a filename relative to the directory you're currently walking over. But `readdir()` returns only the filename relative to the directory you're walking over.

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$fileFolder.'/';
$i = 1; 
$handler = opendir($directory);
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $newName = $i . '.jpg';
        rename($directory.$file, $directory.$newName); // here; prepended a $directory
        $i++;
    }
}
closedir($handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

`readdir()` returns ONLY the filename of the directory you're scanning. Since you opened up a subdir of whatever directory you're running the script, in you need to include that subdir in the rename call, e.g.:

```
    rename($directory . $file, $directory . $newName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$dir = opendir('test');
$i = 1;

// loop through all the files in the directory
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    // if the extension is '.jpg'
    if (strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 'jpg')
    {
        // do the rename based on the current iteration
        $newName = 'test/'. $i . '.jpg';
        $new = 'test/'.$file;
        rename($new, $newName);

        // increase for the next loop
        $i++;
    }
}

// close the directory handle
closedir($dir);
?>
www.codeprojectdownload.com
```

Comment: Worked like a charm ;)